# assigning NumericVector to a column of DataFrame

Tags: r, rcpp

Suppose I have a working function `cfVecCpp` written in `RCpp` that takes a `NumericVector` and returns a `NumericVector` of the same length (and is behaving properly). I am getting errors when I try to run this as a loop over elements of a `DataFrame`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cfVecCpp(NumericVector x,int maxfill=-1){
 .... // code works fine here
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame cfDFCpp(DataFrame x, int maxfill=-1) {
  int nRows=x.nrows();
  int nCols=x.size();

  DataFrame z;
  for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
    NumericVector tmp=cfVecCpp(x[i],maxfill);
    // tmp.attr("dim")=Dimension(nRows,1);
    z[i]=wrap(tmp); // alternative z[i]=tmp;
  }
  // z.attr("names")=x.attr("names");
  return z;
}
```

The `cfDFCpp` function simply tries to loop over the columns of `x`, perform a `cfVecCpp` operation and then return the output.

The code compiles fine. However, when I try to run the code in RStudio as follows:

```
y<-cfDFCpp(x) # where x is data frame whose all columns are numeric
```

I get an error:

```
Error in cfDFCpp(x) : 
  attempt to set index 0/0 in SET_VECTOR_ELT
```

I tried to give attributes (see the commented out code `//` lines), but the error doesn't go away. What could be the issue?

I have even tried replacing `z[i]=wrap(tmp);` with `z[i]=tmp;`. Code compiles fine, but I get the same error when I run the function in `RStudio`.

Comment: I wasn't able to compile your function for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created an empty dataframe `z` you cannot set `z[i]`. You need to use the `push_back()` function. See [constructing a Data Frame in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631197/constructing-a-data-frame-in-rcpp) to learn how to construct a dataframe.

Here is the answer to your question.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cfVecCpp(NumericVector x,int maxfill=-1){
  return(x * 2);
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame cfDFCpp(DataFrame x, int maxfill=-1) {
  int nCols =x.length();
  List zlist(nCols);

  for (int i=0;i<nCols;i++) {
    zlist[i] =cfVecCpp(x[i],maxfill);
  }
  zlist.attr("names") = x.attr("names");
  DataFrame z(zlist); // convert list to DataFrame
  z.attr("row.names") = x.attr("row.names");
  return z;
}
```

Then in R after you have run sourceCpp successfully you can do

```
> data(freeny)

> tail(freeny, 2)
              y lag.quarterly.revenue price.index income.level
1971.5  9.77536               9.74924     4.27839      6.19377
1971.75 9.79424               9.77536     4.27789      6.20030
        market.potential
1971.5           13.1625
1971.75          13.1664
> tail(cfDFCpp(freeny), 2)
               y lag.quarterly.revenue price.index income.level
1971.5  19.55072              19.49848     8.55678     12.38754
1971.75 19.58848              19.55072     8.55578     12.40060
        market.potential
1971.5           26.3250
1971.75          26.3328
```