# How to create list columns using Rcpp?

Tags: r, dataframe, rcpp, tibble

I am working on an Rcpp function that preprocesses some input objects and returns a data.frame as an output. The resulting data.frame will have some regular (e.g., numeric) columns and some list columns (containing matrices). Is it possible to create list columns using Rcpp?

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame create_obj(const List y) {
  // some calculations...
  // some calculations...
  // some calculations...

  DataFrame df = DataFrame::create(Named("V1") = y);
  return df;
}

/*** R
my_list = list(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3))
my_list
create_obj(create_obj(my_list))
*/
```

While the current Rcpp code provides a data frame with 3 observations over 3 columns, I would like an equivalent to this instead: `data.frame(V1 = I(my_list))`.

Comment: Also see _e.g._ the RcppExamples package on CRAN.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I think the OP did use the solution you link. The problem is that the OP wants some columns to be lists (as opposed to atomic vectors), known as list-columns (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1).

Comment: Lists of lists definitely work.  I tend to then just do the required next step (often `setDT()` to create a `data.table` in my usage) once back in R.

Comment: Yes, I want to create list-columns and there is not any answer to that question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631197/constructing-a-data-frame-in-rcpp (I do not think this question is a duplicate).  Dirk Eddelbuettel, could you provide an example on how to create them?

Comment: Just start from https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/ListExample.cpp and stick _that list_ into another list.  Recurse until you have enough.  Back at the R level do what you have to do.  If you want other list support _you may need to write a PR for it_.  Discuss on the rcpp-devel list.